# Log of a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm working on a shell script.
How can I save the log: who executed, when, and also the command into a log.txt file.
So how can I rewrite the command that users use to the log file
Like

```
22/11/2021 - 1:23 - ./submit -l
22/11/2021 - 2:23 - ./submit file1 file2
22/11/2021 - 3:23 - ./submit ...
```

Here is part of my code

```
help() {
    echo "$1 syntax is $1 <option>"
    echo ""
    echo "where the option is one of the following"
    echo " -l -- to print all file u already summited";
    echo "log -- to log"
}

list() {
    ls -l $submitfolder; 
}

log() {
    NOW=`date '+%H:%M_%d/%m/%Y'`
    echo "$NOW - $USER - " >> $logfile;
}

case $1
in
    l | -l) list $@;;
    log) log $@;;
    help | -help | --help) help $@;;
    *) input $@;;
esac
```

Comment: You seem to know how `echo "$NOW - $USER - " >> $logfile;` , only add `"$*"` also.

Comment: Note that `$@` is exactly like `$*` outside quotes. You need to use `"$@"` to get the safer behavior it's meant for.

Comment: Lots of other quoting bugs in this code too. Consider running it through http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: Also, you should be opening your log file only once and reuse the file descriptor. Right now you're re-opening the file every time you want to echo just one line to it.

Comment: I'm just new to this shell scripting thing, so what is file descriptor and easier, how can I use it.
I want to run the log function every time this file run, not to create ./submit log to log a file. This is just for testing.

Comment: Just call `log` at the beginning of your code and add `$0` and `$@` to its `echo` argument.